# UNION and IN operation result set mismatch

Tags: oracle

-- This query to pull current and prior month data by below condition

```
SELECT 

 COL1 ||''||
 COL2 ||''||
 COL2 ||''||

FROM TB1 , TB2 , TB3

WHERE TB1.TRAN_YEAR=2020   AND TB1.PERIOD=(3,2) 
AND TB2.TRAN_YEAR=2020     AND TB2.PERIOD= (3,2)
```

-- This query to pull current and prior month data by UNION

```
SELECT 

 COL1 ||''||
 COL2 ||''||
 COL2 ||''||

FROM TB1 , TB2 , TB3

WHERE TB1.TRAN_YEAR=2020   AND TB1.PERIOD=(3) 
AND TB2.TRAN_YEAR=2020     AND TB2.PERIOD= (3)

UNION

SELECT 

 COL1 ||''||
 COL2 ||''||
 COL2 ||''||

FROM TB1 , TB2 , TB3

WHERE TB1.TRAN_YEAR=2020   AND TB1.PERIOD=(2) 
AND TB2.TRAN_YEAR=2020     AND TB2.PERIOD= (2)
```

The result set mismatch is there , let me know what needs a changes in first query to make same record count. Need to come up with new query to pull back 12 months of data and it looks odd to add UNION for 12 months.

Comment: Both your queries have syntax errors as you have `COL2||''||` with no expression on the right-hand side of the concatenation operator and `=(3,2)` will give `ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join results per your periods.

```sql
SELECT 

 COL1 ||''||
 COL2 ||''||
 COL2 ||''||

FROM TB1 , TB2 , TB3

WHERE TB1.TRAN_YEAR=2020   AND TB1.PERIOD in (3,2) -- use in to check, that value is in list
AND TB2.TRAN_YEAR=2020
AND (TB1.PERIOD is null or TB2.PERIOD is null or TB1.PERIOD = TB2.PERIOD)
```

Comment: Thanks Manushin ! just figured out by having both conditions in check  TB1.TRAN_YEAR=TB2.TRAN_YEAR AND TB1.PERIOD = TB2.PERIOD

Answer (score 0):

Your first query return data for TB1.PERIOD=3 and TB2.PERIOD=2 or TB1.PERIOD=2 and TB2.PERIOD=3 - this is mismatch. Try that:

```
WHERE 
    TB1.TRAN_YEAR=2020 AND TB2.TRAN_YEAR=2020 
    AND ((TB1.PERIOD=3 AND TB2.PERIOD=3) OR (TB1.PERIOD=2 AND TB2.PERIOD=2))
```

or more clarify:

```
WHERE 
    TB1.TRAN_YEAR=2020 AND TB2.TRAN_YEAR=2020 
    AND TB1.PERIOD=TB2.PERIOD and TB1.PERIOD in (2, 3)
```